# code coloring and positioning in the postings

Tags: text-coloring

how can I coloring for example scheme code and indent the lines correctly in the question postings ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do it on this site, just put 4 spaces in front of each line of code.

If you're trying to add this functionality to your own site, you could try using GeSHi. http://qbnz.com/highlighter/